# Unknown html tag inside json response using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the following problem, I use Codeigniter Controller to produce a Json output. My **Controller** is:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Json extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model ('functionsonproducts'); 
    }

function index(){
    $data ['rows'] = $this->functionsonproducts->getProducts ();
    echo json_encode($data ['rows']);
      }
  }
```

I want to get the following result

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Milk","description":"200gr","price":"10"},{"id":"3","name":"","description":"","price":"0"}]
```

but when I call the Controller's function with jquery, like

**Jquery**

```
  $.get("http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/json/index",
    function(data){
     console.log(data);
    });
```

I get an unknown < /html> tag at the end, so if I try to use the jquery's json parser it produces an error because of this unwanted tag.

**Console output:**

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Milk","description":"200gr","price":"10"},{"id":"3","name":"","description":"","price":"0"}]</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the source of the page when you requested it directly via the URL? It might not show up if you just requested the page and looked at the render

Comment: You are right, the source of the page contains also this unwanted < /html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure where in your code that tag is coming from, but put a return; after the json_endcode() statement and you'll stop anything else from being echo'd

Comment: I put the return after the json_endcode() but it didn't work, the result is the same.

Comment: Finally I found the solution, instead of the **return** I used **exit**.

Comment: you'll want to look at your code more closely - if return isn't working, something is prolly set up incorrectly

Comment: Codeigniter automatically send html for every requests, that was the problem.

Comment: it shouldn't unless you are rendering a view. a Codeigniter function is simply a function

Answer (score 0):

In your **controller**:

```
class Json extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('functionsonproducts'); 
}
function index()
{
    $functionsOnProducts = $this->functionsonproducts->getProducts();
    echo json_encode($functionsOnProducts);
}
}
```

In your **view**:

```
function getAllFunctionsOnProducts() {
    $.ajax({type : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/json/index",
        data : { },
        success : function(result){
            var functionsOnProducts= jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(funtionsOnProducts);
            /* If you want to go through every product:
               jQuery.each(functionsOnProducts,function(){
            })
            */
}
```